# Vertically Center Div

Tags: html, css, styling

I've searched and read other posts, but none seem to work for me. I simply have an overlay that I toggle which has a loading animation. I need the animation to be horizontally and vertically centered. I can't get the vertical piece to work.
CSS for overlay div and div that contains animation:

```
#pageOverlay {
  opacity:    0.5; 
  background: #000; 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    10;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed;
  cursor: wait;
}
#floatingBarsG{
position:relative;
width:62px;
height:77px;
margin: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pageOverlay">
            <div id="floatingBarsG"> 
                <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_02"></div>
                <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_03"></div>
                <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_04"></div>
                <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_06"></div>
                <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_07"></div>
                <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_08"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeBj6/)

Comment: @Dundee Aligning vertically is unfortunately a bit more complicated than horizontally. Different solutions are required

Comment: @Askanison4 Ooops... my eyes have seen what they wanted instead of what's written there. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `top:50%;` and `margin-top:-38px;` on `#floatingBarsG` like this:

```
#floatingBarsG{
    ...
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-38px;
}
```

The `margin-top` needs to be the half of the `height`.

Check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeBj6/2/) to see its working.

Answer (score 1):

[**See your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeBj6/1/)

Since your `#floatingBarsG` div has a fixed width and height, you can use the following CSS:

```
#floatingBarsG{
    position:absolute; /* Change the position to absolute. */
    width:62px;
    height:77px;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

By changing the `position` to `absolute`, and by setting the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties, combined with `margin: auto`, your loading div will vertically center itself.

Keep in mind that this method of vertical centering only works when your centered element has a **fixed height or a minimum height**, and when its parent element has a `position` that is not `static`.

[C Travel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22993339/2038227) is more cross-browser (mine won't work in IE8 and below, I believe), but only works with a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

```
How about this (I added a border around the animation for clarity):

#pageOverlay {
  opacity:    0.5; 
  background: #000; 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    10;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed;
  cursor: wait;
}

#floatingBarsG{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position:relative;
    width:62px;
    height:77px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -38px;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle of this](http://jsfiddle.net/bergonom/FKza6/1/).

Comment: You should explain what you have done with the code... instead of just copy pasting is...

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else seems to be posting examples using line-height, here's mine:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qH9N/1/)

This works by having a parent with a fixed height and line height:

`.parent { height: 50px; line-height: 50px; }`

and then using these properties on the child:

`.child { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: You should use your example on the JSFiddle from the OP, that it will make it easier for the OP to use it.